# How do I subset data with arrays in DATA STEP (SAS)?

Tags: sas, subset, datastep

```
DATA output;
    SET arbitrary_table;
    ARRAY arrayname $ arrayname_1 - arrayname_10;

    DO i = 1 TO 10;
        IF arrayname(i) = "x";
    END;
RUN;
```

The above code won't work. I'm trying to only show observations where one of the arrayname columns contain "x".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that it doesn't work is that subsetting `if` will immediately `return` and not continue processing if it encounters a `false` value.  This is equivalent to:

```
DATA output;
    SET arbitrary_table;
    ARRAY arrayname $ arrayname_1 - arrayname_10;

    DO i = 1 TO 10;
        IF arrayname(i) ne "x" then delete; 
    END;
RUN;
```

What you need to do is to identify if *any* value is true, and `if` only if that is true.  You could use `whichc` as Reeza points out (which returns a TRUE value if it finds the value you're looking for, or FALSE if it doesn't); or you could iterate in the similar fashion like so:

```
DATA output;
    SET arbitrary_table;
    ARRAY arrayname $ arrayname_1 - arrayname_10;
    has_x=0;
    DO i = 1 TO 10;
        IF arrayname(i) = "x" then has_x=1;
    END;
    if has_x;
RUN;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DATA output;
    SET arbitrary_table;
    ARRAY arrayname $ arrayname_1 - arrayname_10;

    if whichc('x', of arrayname(*));
RUN;
```

Try using WHICHC instead to filter the record.